# Really good modern fight scenes!

Tags: sound-effects

Off the top of my head I'm thinking "Hanna" and "The bourne" films.
Working on something and was hoping to get inspired.
Anyone think of some really "big" fight scenes from recent films? Not kung fu hustle type. I'm working on a project thats two guys against a crowd type a deal?

Answer (score 1):

The final fist fight at the end of "Gangster Squad" was expertly constructed and is a great example of a realistic take on two men trying to beat each other into submission.

Comment: What you describe reminds me of two specific fight scenes in "Safe House" too.

Answer (score 0):

Jay, you're so humble about it... hehe. That was an extremely well done scene!!!

Columbiana has some great scenes,

Knight and Day had some good fist fighting on the airplane,

Mission Impossible 4 ending scene inside the parking garage,

The Warrior had great sequences,

Fight Club for sure,

Great sounding fight scenes in Lawless, as well. (I especially liked the one where Shia LaBeouf gets pulverized)

But, my all-time favorite fist-fighting scene ever was Indiana Jones against the gigantic Nazi in front of the airplane trying to take off (Lost Ark? Forget which one it was in). Those punches were epic - so much so that I instantly recognized them being re-used in the newest one (Crystal Skull).

Comment: @Utopia, I didn't work on that sequence - it was designed by Lee Gilmore.

Comment: @Jay Ah ok. Well, awesomeness nonetheless :)

Answer (score 0):

Safe House, Hanna, and fight club are my top for favorite fight sequences as far as mixing and editorial goes. Hands down.